# Configuring a single Jenkins job for multiple maven projects

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have 3 library projects based on Maven, A, B, and C.
A
-- B
--  --C
Here C is dependent on both A & B and B is dependent on A.
Now I want to know, how can I configure a Jenkins job in such a way that a single job runs all three projects as per their dependency order?

Things I did: I created 3 Jenkins job and adding a relationship between them as per their build order.
I want a single job to do this. I might be missing something. Any help will be great.

Comment: What about one job with 3 build steps? One for each dependency.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, how to specify 3 projects under a single job, without creating 2 more jobs for 2 dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Create a pipeline job with 3 stage can solve it.

```
   ....
        stages {
          stage ('build A') {
               (steps in A)
          }
          stage ('build B') {
               (steps in B)
          }
          stage ('build C') {
               (steps in C)
          }
        }
        ...
```

In pipeline each stage depends on the result of previous one. You can print logs at each stage. Hope it helps.

Comment: This will be a manual process and also for implementing this, I first require to know the dependency order. Can't be this automatically taken and build as per their dependency order?

Comment: So far as I know, the dependency order in pipeline should be set manually. You  can write a method to assign the dependency order and then use it in pipeline. Check the groovy tutorial.

Comment: Will I require 3 jobs or only a single job? If a single job, how I can get 3 projects in a single job and build them separately?

Comment: A single job. I haven't tried it before. Here is another answer about "multijobs pipeline".   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998433/jenkins-pipeline-to-build-multiple-projects-in-sequence